# Which storage mechanism to use in html5 app for Windows Phone?

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, local-storage

Which storage mechanism to use in html5 app for Windows Phone?

If I user Index DB then What is the quota limit?
or Can I read or write files? How to do so.